# 500.30 IIS publish .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

When i publish the my .net core 3.1 web app i got the HTTP ERROR 500.30...

I think everythink ok my project i'm using vstudio 2019 and my project works fine.

My log like this i tried many things but i can't find the solution

Thank you share your time with my problem..

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-12-29 11:53:39
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-12-29 11:53:39 ::1 GET /trying/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/87.0.4280.88+Safari/537.36+OPR/73.0.3856.284 - 500 30 574 1654
2020-12-29 11:53:39 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/87.0.4280.88+Safari/537.36+OPR/73.0.3856.284 http://localhost/trying/ 404 0 2 140
```

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report first.

Comment: Did you install the asp.net core 3.1 sdk, runtime and host bundle? If you have installed them, try to set hostingModel="outofprocess" and run again.